# Rails 3 working with data attributes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, custom-data-attribute

I am working on a form that does an autosave functionality and am having an issue working with `data-*` attributes..

Here is an input:

```
<input class="span2 autosave" data-athlete-id="58" data-event="blur" data-object-name="stat" data-stat-type-id="1" data-url="/stats" id="stat_value" maxlength="4" name="stat[value]" size="4" type="text" value="4.04">
```

When I serialize this input to pass it to my `StatsController`, `athlete_id` is passed in as `athleteId`... how do I pass in the data-attribute of athlete_id as athlete_id (or any data attr that's longer than one word)?

Comment: Have you tried `data-athlete_id`?

Comment: Thanks! That solved it for me! Can you put your comment in an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer you are looking for is `data-athlete_id`